# Seaborn plot per column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, foreach, seaborn

I have a little dataframe that looks somewhat like this:

```
csv = [{"Oranges" : 12, "Apples" : 4, "Kiwis" : "Yes"}, {"Oranges" : 1, "Apples" : 8, "Kiwis" : "No"}, {"Oranges" : 1, "Apples" : 14, "Kiwis" : "Yes"}, {"Oranges" : 11, "Apples" : 3, "Kiwis" : "No"}, ]
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
```

Only, it has many more cols. I want to plot a seaborn violin plot per column. If I create the plot per column manually, it would look somewhat like this:

```
sns.violinplot(y="Oranges", x="Kiwis", data=df, split=True, inner="quart")
sns.violinplot(y="Apples", x="Kiwis", data=df, split=True, inner="quart")
```

However, and given about 100 cols, I'd like to loop through the dataframe col by col.

I tried building a tiny function like follows:

```
def violin(col):
    sns.violinplot(y=col, x="Kiwis", data=df, split=True, inner="quart")
```

My idea is to use `apply()` to use it for each column...but it doesent work this far.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for column `Kiwis` and then use `apply` with selecting columns by subset `[]`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def violin(col):
    sns.violinplot(y=col, x="Kiwis", data=df, split=True, inner="quart")
    plt.figure()


cols = df.columns.difference(['Kiwis'])
df[cols].apply(violin)
```

Comment: I got the following error: `"Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional", 'occurred at index category')"`. I proceeded to define the `df` as `df_num = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float])`. Now it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to slightly reformat your dataframe then you can do the whole plot in one call:

```
df = pd.melt(df, "Kiwis", var_name="Fruit", value_name="Value")
```

Makes things look like

```
  Kiwis    Fruit  Value
0   Yes   Apples      4
1    No   Apples      8
2   Yes   Apples     14
3    No   Apples      3
4   Yes  Oranges     12
5    No  Oranges      1
6   Yes  Oranges      1
7    No  Oranges     11
```

Which is simple to plot with

```
sns.violinplot(x="Fruit", y="Value", hue="Kiwis", data=df,
           split=True, inner="quart")
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool solution! However, I got about 200 figures - hence the solution for individual plots seems better in this case.